# dev site running on subdomain is redirecting to the main domain

Tags: sql, wordpress, subdomain, hosting

I wanted to create a dev site for my main wordpress site. So I copied my wordpress files to the virtual host server and imported the database from my main site. Then I ran `wp search-replace 'www.mobisium.com' 'dev.mobisium.com'` (main site= 'www.mobisium.com' dev='dev.mobisium.com') to change the database url's. Then I created a dns for dev.mobisium.com using cloudflare. But now when I visit dev.mobisium.com it redirects me to the main domain mobisium.com. I don't know much about wordpress and server management. I just followed my colleague instructions.

Solutions I tried:

- tried adding `define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com');`
  `define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com');` to wp-config
  file.
- adding home and site URL in wp_options in the database, but there is
  no home and site URL in wp_options in the database.

Comment: The `wp search-replace` is the correct way to go. The question is: did you set up the virtual host of the webserver correctly (pointing to the right directory), and the database settings in `wp-config.php` of the clone pointing to the database copy?

Comment: I have pointed the database settings to the new database I created and the imported the old database. then I ran the command wp search-replace

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache? Just in case the 301 response is still cached. Other than that, the cloudflare server sets the header `x-redirect-by: WordPress` - so, WP is at fault. Did you actually make sure the URL change worked? `wp` should've displayed some output on how many entries were replaced.

Comment: wp search-replace showed 10361 entries replaced which is correct I guess. I also tried to change site and home URL from wp_config file, If URL were not changed by any chance at least this should have worked. How to check if URL change worked?